# r min function does not return the correct number of decimals

Tags: r, decimal, precision, min, numeric

In R I am using the min function on a vector of numeric values, like this vector:

```
v <- c(16.22900, 16.28857, 16.47363, 16.47412, 16.00000, 16.49463, 16.27246, 16.0366, 16.49609)
```

However when I apply the min function, I get this return value

```
min(v)
[1] 16
```

instead I would like this result:

```
[1] 16.00000
```

I checked the class of the vector but all seems ok

```
class(v)
[1] "numeric"
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: I don't know if it's a problem, but R doesn't display trailing zeroes. If it's for output/printing reasons, you could try `sprintf("%.5f", min(v))`. Probably superfluous, but that results in a string.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need those trailing zeroes to do some high precision calculations, not for printing.

Comment: You misunderstand. 16.0000 is still the same as 16.0.

Comment: They are still there, they are just not displayed. `16*0.12345` yields  1.9752, `16.0000*0.12345` yields the same.

Comment: min() returns the right result. Your desired result depends on somewhat that you don't show to us. R (without any additional packages) is not an arbitrary precision calculator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are caught between *internal representation of a value* and how *it is displayed*.

```
R> v <- c(16.22900, 16.28857, 16.47363, 16.47412, 16.00000, 
+         16.49463, 16.27246, 16.0366, 16.49609)
R> min(v)
[1] 16
R> sprintf("%10.8f", min(v))
[1] "16.00000000"
R> identical(min(v), 16.0000000000000000000)
[1] TRUE
R>
```